# How to disable multiple operations in a single graphql request

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

Graphql support multiple operations in a single request. It means an unbounded number of graphql queries can be submitted in a single HTTP request which will cause some security issue. Is there a way to only allow a single operation in a single graphql request?